# HTML table with one column fixed width and the others fluid and equal width

Tags: css, html-table

I have an HTML table. I need the first column to be 100px wide and all the others to be fluid and the same width.

All of my widths are ignored with this code:

```
 table {
  border: 1px solid green;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 50%;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  border-color: gold;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the width also to the header like:

```css
th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}
```